# Registering an icon for my application's document type

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode

I'm trying to register an icon for my app's document type. After reading [Declaring New Uniform Type Identifiers](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis_declare/understand_utis_declare.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001319-CH204-SW1) and looking at `/Developer/Examples/Sketch` I came up with something like this in my `Info.plist`:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
  <dict>
    <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
    <string>Viewer</string>
    <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
    <array>
      <string>com.mycompany.myextension</string>
    </array>
    <key>NSDocumentClass</key>
    <string>NSString</string>
  </dict>
</array>

...

<key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
<array>
  <dict>
    <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
    <string>Blah blah blah</string>
    <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
    <array>
      <string>public.data</string>
    </array>
    <key>UTTypeIconFile</key>
    <string>My-file-icon.icns</string>
    <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.mycompany.myextension</string>
    <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
    <dict>
      <key>public.filename-extension</key>
      <array>
        <string>myextension</string>
      </array>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</array>
```

Now, everything is fine and dandy, i.e. my program is opened when I click on a file with my extension, etc. However, the document icon is not registered with the OS, i.e. I see an ugly blank icon instead of my beautiful `My-file-icon.icns`. I suspect that I'm missing something in the plist above, any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try putting the icon name in the `CFBundleTypeIconFile` key in the `CFBundleDocumentTypes` array, not in the `UTExportedTypeDeclarations` array.

And of course make sure that "My-file-icon.icns" is in your target's Copy Bundle Resources build phase and is being copied into Contents/Resources in your app's bundle.

Comment: Yep, that was it. CFBundleTypeIconFile has to be in CFBundleDocumentTypes.

Answer (score 5):

I've been trying to do this in Xcode 11 and it's been a challenge. There are lots of answers here on SO to questions like this but I couldn't find one that had everything I needed to get this working. I'll try to do that here.

[Technical Q&A QA1587](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1587/_index.html) Although this is a bit old I think it has everything required but it's a bit vague in some spots like when it says `Provide an icon for the document.`

I thought I could make it work with an icon in `Assets.xcassets` but it didn't work for me until I provided an `icns` file. I took the 1024x1024 `png` app icon and converted it to an `icns` here at [cloudconvert](https://cloudconvert.com/png-to-icns). Then I added that `icns` to my project. I don't think it matters where you put it. I put it just below the top level. It's circled in the image below.

[image]
Follow the arrows in the image and you end up at the Info tab. I tapped the Add button to create a Document Type and filled it in as shown. When you tap the Add button in the icon section it will ask you for an `icns` file. Once I had mine in the project it appeared in the window and I could select it.

Same for Configured UTIs.

That was it. In Files, Messages, or Mail the icon appears.

Comment: Works fine. But Equivalent Types is now instead of UITypeTagSpecification. Read https://www.raywenderlich.com/813044-uiactivityviewcontroller-tutorial-sharing-data

Comment: Equivalent Types = UTTypeSpecification

Answer (score 4):

Your UTI declaration in the Info.plist appears to be correct, however I noticed an other issue. If you application is a document-based application you need to replace the NSString in following entry with your NSDocument subclass:

```
<key>NSDocumentClass</key>
<string>NSString</string>
```

For example it's "SKTDocument" in Sketch:

```
<key>NSDocumentClass</key>
<string>SKTDocument</string>
```

Edit: 
Please also make sure to use your own reverse domain name for your exported UTIs. This ensures that UTIs are unique. For example its com.mindnode.MindNode.MindNodeDocument in my case.

Comment: Thanks, I'll fix that. Still don't understand why the icon doesn't get registered, though.

Answer (score 3):

I also had a similar problem, turns out I needed to rebuild the launch services database as per what i have documented here....

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12466968/1571635

Comment: I ensured the icon has `.icns` in the name and then rebuilt the LS database per this answer and that fixed it for me.