# NSDocument custom icon not displaying in Finder but displaying in Quick Look

Tags: macos, xcode6, osx-yosemite, nsdocument

I'm designing a custom application and I've set a custom icon for my file type.

I've put the icon on both Document Types and Exported UTIs section (filling in other values too, obviously).

Here is what I get when I run:

[image]

No icon is defined in Finder

[image]

But in Quick Look, it displays correctly.

I've seen [CFBundleTypeIconFile Icon not showing for given file extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12465937/cfbundletypeiconfile-icon-not-showing-for-given-file-extension/12466968#12466968) and tried rebuilding the launch services database. I've restarted Finder, cleaned Xcode project/derived data etc. and re-run, but nothing changed. Finder still doesn't display my icon. My ICNS file has all the required sizes contained. Everything works fine otherwise (when I double click it opens correctly with my app etc). By the way, my file DOES have the extension, it just doesn't display in Finder. I can verify that it has the correct extension by `ls`ing in terminal.

How can I make Finder show my icon?

Comment: Hi, did solve the problem? Having a similar issue here.

Comment: @Daniel unfortunately not, I couldn't solve it. would be glad if you find the answer and post it.

Comment: I noticed that on a new user account, everything works as expected. Now after the last restart of my Mac it also works on my user account. Surprisingly, I did rebuild launch services database before, but it didn't work. Not sure what the restart did in the end.

Comment: Well I've restarted a dozen of times, but no avail :( @Daniel

Comment: Try it on a new user account. Does it work there?

Answer (score 2):

I found this [solution](http://furbo.org/2015/01/19/clearing-the-icon-services-cache-in-yosemite/), which worked for me. I did not have to restart my Mac, just the Finder (I have a little AppleScriptlet to tell it to quit).

Execute the following commands:

```
sudo find /private/var/folders/ -name com.apple.dock.iconcache -exec rm {} \;
sudo find /private/var/folders/ -name com.apple.iconservices -exec rm -rf {} \;
sudo rm -rf /Library/Caches/com.apple.iconservices.store
killall Finder
```

Then relaunch the Finder or log out and back in, or restart your Mac.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a very simple solution :

1. right click on a file icon and select "show presentation options"
   select
2. then deselect the checkbox at the bottom (Use content
   outline as icon) NB: I have a french speaking system, so I'm not
   sure how it is in US Finder
3. icons appear magically !