# Adding file icon to custom file type in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, cfbundledocumenttypes

I'm trying to add an icon (a PNG named "FileIcon") to a custom file type in Xcode 13, but can't seem to actually add it via the interface in Xcode:

[image]

Any other way to do this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771601/registering-an-icon-for-my-applications-document-type

Comment: @matt I tried all the suggested responses in that question and still have the issue; that question was first asked 11 years ago

Comment: I have the same problem with iOS 15.1 and XCode 13.1. Did you find how to solve your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per Apple's article [Setting Up a Document Browser App](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers/adding_a_document_browser_to_your_app/setting_up_a_document_browser_app), there is a snippet in there for the plist:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
        <array/>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Text</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.data</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Is this set up correctly in your plist?

Comment: Hey @bri! Yes; I believe so - just updated my answer under EDIT 3 with that entry

Comment: @narner - Ah, looks like in your `info.plist` the `Document Types -> Item 0 -> Document Content Type Identifiers -> Item 0` and `Exported Type Identifiers -> Item 0 -> Identifier` do not match.

Comment: ah had put a screenshot from an example; just updated w/the actual, up to date plist entries I'm using - ty!!